# Is the phrase 'medium appearance residential buildings' is correct grammatically?

Tags: grammar, meaning

If it is, whats the first meaning that you get from it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: It is a noun phrase.If I try to make sense of it, I'd say it is "residential buildings of medium appearance" though I have no real idea what "medium appearance" means.  "medium" is not really a proper descriptor for "appearance".  You could say "medium height" or "medium price" but "appearance" is not scalable.

Comment: Do not delete and repost questions, you should edit it instead to address any feedback from the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not correct. You can have a "large building" or perhaps a "medium-large building".  You cannot have an "appearance building" or a "medium-appearance building"

You can say "medium-large" since there is a clear, one-dimension scale of "size" from tiny to huge. You can be larger, or less large.

However, "appearance" is an abstract noun.  There is no meaning to "more appearance" or "less appearance", so a building cannot be "medium appearance"

You can say "nondescript building" or "a building with an average appearance" (but this is rather unclear) or "A building in a moderate state of repair", for example.